# How to plot 2D vectors

Tags: python

I would like to plot vector[3,3] and [2,-2]

But it turns out that the result is incorrect.
Can anyone fix my code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

soa = np.array([[3,3], [2,-2]])
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(soa[0], soa[1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
ax.set_xlim([-2, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-2, 5])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You want 2 vectors to be plotted?

Comment: @nithin11 yes!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quiver` expects the origins of your vectors and the coordinates as columns

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

soa = np.array([[3,3], [2,-2]])
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.quiver(*np.zeros_like(soa.T), *soa.T, angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, color=['r','g'])
ax.set_xlim([-2, 5])
ax.set_ylim([-2, 5]);
```

Out:

[image: two vectors]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in your piece of code

```
origin = np.array([[0, 0],[0, 0]])
ax.quiver(*origin, soa[0], soa[1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
```